# Hyperlinks don't like display flex in parent element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My hyperlinks in my `li` elements are displaying incredibly weirdly. They are wrapping on words and etc. Please see the example below for the error as its hard to explain.

I know the cause is my css `li { display: flex; }` but I need this to vertically align the bullet correctly. How can I fix the display of my anchors in my `li` elements to display 'normally'?

```css
ol,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ol {
  counter-reset: foo;
  display: table;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  counter-increment: foo;
  display: flex;
}

li::before {
  content: "•";
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: .3em;
  color: $mht-blue;
  font-size: 225%;
  line-height: .6;
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li>
    How can I make the dot vertically lower? Ie, centered on the first line of text? sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et <a href="">dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad</a> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It would be great if you could accept the answer that best solve your question, or if none did, or let us know what is missing, so we can find one that does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ol,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ol {
  counter-reset: foo;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

li::before {
  content: "•";
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: .3em;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 225%;
  line-height: .6em;
  margin-left: -.75em;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li>
    How can I make the dot vertically lower? Ie, centered on the first line of text? sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et <a href="">dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad</a> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Use float:left and negative margin to put the bullet in place.

Comment: Please remove styles for `ol` because they are not relevant and specify that `float: left;` and negative margin are doing the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Put the text in another element so that the `a` isn't a flex child.

```css
ol,
li,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ol {
  counter-reset: foo;
  display: table;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  counter-increment: foo;
  display: flex;
}

li::before {
  content: "•";
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: .3em;
  color: $mht-blue;
  font-size: 225%;
  line-height: .6;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>
      How can I make the dot vertically lower? Ie, centered on the first line of text? sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et <a href="">dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad</a> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
      ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks that works but my users will be using a CMS rich text editor. Which means they can create `ul`'s and I don't have much control over making them place `p`'s inside each `li`. Is there a css solution such as `li > a { display: something?; }`. I've tried `display: inline-block;` and others but not luck. Any ideas?